# google colaboratory not refreshing drive content?

Tags: google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d
It shows content pulled via Google jupyter notebook into G Drive. The tutorial shows folders/files in the G Drive folders. Some of the files/folders I've pulled into G Drive show up in my G Drive folder, but not all.

I've noticed that G Drive UI does not reflect/refresh to show new Drive content imported via notebook.

Is this a bug or feature?

[image: notebook shows drive content but drive does not]

Comment: Google colab is run on a separate instance and doesn't use google drive for storage, so if you create any file/folder on notebook it wouldn't show up on google drive.

Answer (score 8):

Run this on the notebook:

```
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -cc
```

This will clear the cache and refresh the files. Every time you change a file in drive folder, you should call this command and the mounted drive would refresh with the changes.

Comment: If you are following this guide: https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d ocamlfuse should have been installed already.

Comment: `/bin/bash: google-drive-ocamlfuse: command not found`. Any help regarding this?

Comment: The guide provided used ocamlfuse to mount the drive before. I've checked again, the author has edited that part completely.

Comment: Whatever happens, happens.

Comment: I also get `/bin/bash: google-drive-ocamlfuse: command not found` message.

Answer (score 2):

If you changed something in your drive after you did the `drive.mount('/content/drive')`, you have to remount it with `drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)`.

Comment: restarted colab runtime

Comment: then remounted, didnt help